# WPF databinding - set NotifyOnValidationError to true for all bindings with validation rules

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

In my WPF application, I want to set `NotifyOnValidationError` to `true` (the framework defaults it to false) for all child controls/bindings if they have any ValidationRules attached to the binding. Indeed, it would be nice to specify other binding defaults too - e.g. `ValidatesOnDataErrors` should also always be true.

For example, in the following text box I don't want to have to manually specify the NotifyOnValidationError property.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="PostalCode" 
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <rules:PostalCodeRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Binding` is just a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx) you could create a custom [Markup Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) that extends `Binding` and sets those properties to your desired defaults.

Answer (score 7):

Following up on *Ragepotato's* answer.
The easiest way to do this is to create your own `Binding` that inherits from `Binding` and then set the things you need, like `NotifyOnValidationError="True"` and `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` in the constructor.

```
public class ExBinding : Binding
{
    public ExBinding()
    {
        NotifyOnValidationError = true;
        ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    }
}
```

And then you use this Binding instead

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <local:ExBinding Path="PostalCode">
            <local:ExBinding.ValidationRules>
                <rules:PostalCodeRule />
            </local:ExBinding.ValidationRules>
        </local:ExBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```