# Raise Validation.Error without NotifyOnValidationError. Is posible?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

Is posible to force a control to raise the **Validation.Error** event, even when the binding doesn't specify the **NotifyOnValidationError**?

Or

Is there another event that raises always when the red validation border is shown or hidden?

**Explanation:**

I have an attached behaviour that makes a binding between the **Validation.GetHasError** and a property of my ViewModel. This with the purpose of knowing on the view model side, when a View side validation has happened.

Example: A view model with an **int** property

```
class ViewModel
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

A text box:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Validation.Error="Validation_Handler" />
```

**Example** I want to know when the user enter a value that it is not an integer.

Modifying all view model properties to have **string** type and have all validation done on the ViewModel is not feasible because some ViewModel properties are generated dynamically on run time, and I want to preserve the default converter behavior.

Comment: ValidationRules could help you to implement validations. Check this link http://miteshsureja.blogspot.in/2011/08/validation-rules-in-wpf.html

Comment: The problem is that validation rules do not fire when the conversion fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099064/wpf-databinding-set-notifyonvalidationerror-to-true-for-all-bindings-with-vali) question

The easiest solution was to inherit the **Binding** class and set the **NotifyOnValidationError** to true on the constructor. This way the **Validation.Error** event is always triggered.

```
public class Binding : System.Data.Binding
{
    public Binding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{ui:Binding Value}" Validation.Error="Validation_Handler" />
```

Instead of:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, NotifyOnValidationError='True'}" Validation.Error="Validation_Handler" />
```